# hibernate validator - custom factory validates twice

Tags: hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Using a custom `ConstraintValidatorFactory` which is aware of the hibernate session by adding it to the configuration using following code results in double validation on any operation (create, update) this factory is responsible of.

Validator `ValidBeanDatabase` in this example is invoked twice with different instances.
All other constraint's are validated once (`@ValidBean` as an example).

The implementation of the factory and validator's is similar to the one in this post:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AccessingTheHibernateSessionWithinAConstraintValidator

**validation.xml**

```
<constraint-validator-factory>package.SessionConstraintValidatorFactory</constraint-validator-factory>
<constraint-mapping>package/Bean-validation.xml</constraint-mapping>
```

**Java:**

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

// get ValidatorFactory from validation.xml
final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure()
            .buildValidatorFactory();

// ... add SessionFactory to custom ConstraintValidatorFactory
((SessionConstraintValidatorFactory)validatorFactory.getConstraintValidatorFactory()).setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

// set ValidatorFactory
configuration.getProperties().put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validatorFactory);
```

**Bean:**

```
@GroupSequence(value =
{
    Bean.class, Create.class
})
@ValidBean // custom class-level constraint
public class Bean
{
    // properties and validator annotations
}
```

**Bean-validation.xml**

Adding Hibernate session aware constraint via xml mapping.

```
<bean class="Bean" ignore-annotations="false">
    <class>
        <constraint annotation="package.ValidBeanDatabase">
            <groups>
                <value>package.groups.Create</value>
            </groups>
        </constraint>
    </class>
</bean>
```

Edit:

**Hibernate-Configuration**

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist">
    javax.validation.groups.Default, package.groups.Create
</property>
```

*Glassfish 3.1.2
with Hibernate Validator 4.2*

@Gunner
*Do you have any validation-related configuration in other places, e.g. persistence.xml?* **No**

Comment: Some questions for clarification: How are you triggering validation? How is the `configuration` object used in the following? Do you have any validation-related configuration in other places, e.g. persistence.xml?Btw. you don't have to specify the constraint validator factory in XML, just pass it when putting the ValidatorFactory into the configuration object: ValidatorFactory vf = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().constraintValidatorFactory( new SessionConstraintValidatorFactory ( sessionFactory ).getValidatorFactory();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint is validated twice because you specify two groups for validation upon pre-persist in your file "Hibernate-Configuration" , `Default` and `Create`.

The constraint is part of the `Create` group as per your XML mapping, while the default group sequence of type `Bean` also contains this group (as per the `@GroupSequence` annotation on `Bean`). The constraint is therefore validated twice, once as part of the default group and once as part of the `Create` group.

So you either validate only one group upon pre-persist or you change the default group sequence of the `Bean` type.